# psd to html slice error

Tags: html, css, psd

I am beginner level front end developer i need help in psd to html when I slice 
the image its size is 1920px and in html, div size is 100% but image is going out of the browser. What are my mistakes kindly help me what should I have to do to make it good I  want to learn PSD to html. 
Also  guide me how to use slice tool in adobe Photoshop ?

```css
html, body { margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; }

#wrap{
        width: 1920px;
        background-color: #e7e7e7;
}
.menu{

        width: 100%;
        background-color: #202628;
}

.slider{
    width: 100%;
    
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>psd to html</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" content="text/html" http-equiv="content-type">
        <link href="css/index.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
        
    </head>
    <body>
        
        <div id="wrap">
            <header>
                
                <ul class="menu">
                    <li><a href="index.html">SiteName</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index.html">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index.html">Services</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index.html">Portfolio</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index.html">Contact</a></li>
                    
                </ul>
                
                <div class="slider">
                    <img src="images/banner.png" alt="banner">
                </div><!-- end slider-->
                
            </header><!--end header-->
        </div><!-- end wrap -->
        
        
    </body>
</html>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should add css for image tag and also remove fix width of your #wrap and apply max-width.

Try this:

```
#wrap{
    max-width:1920px;
    width:100%;
}

.slider img{
    width: 100%;
    max-width:100%;    
}
```

Comment: thanks :) can you please guide me what is the reason ? :)

Comment: you set fixed width for main container, so if screen width is smaller the 1920px it's taking 1920px width instead of your screen width..and also Horizontal   scrollbar coming in your screen, So always prefer to giving max-width of your main container..